# Che programmi hai per + article/no article?

Tags: articles

Why do you say: "che programmi hai per il pomeriggio/l'estate/le vacanze/il fine di settimana" but then "sabato/Capodanno/gennaio etc.? Is there any rule when to use an article? Thank you :)

Comment: It's just the same as in English for the cases you quote.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Krzysztof!

Comment: Thanks, but English is not my native language so I would be confused as well. Is there any rule then?

Comment: @Nico While that is true, the rules are not *exactly* the same as in English and, even if they were, asking for them here would still be on topic.

Comment: Let me reiterate that discussion of moderation activities needs to be done on Meta, not on the comments to a question. All futher comments not related to this question will be removed.

Comment: My question was if there is any rule when to use an article in Italian language with the question I mentioned and not only those several examples I wrote. The comparison to English doesn't help much in my case but thanks anyway. Anybody else knows :)?

Comment: @DaG: Do you think that this has something to do with what it's explained in Serianni, *Italiano*, IV.18 and IV.72.i)?

Comment: @DaG:  And maybe what happens with names of festivities is that some of them are usually written without article (Natale, Capodanno, Ferragosto, Pasqua, ...), whereas other ones are usually written with article (il Primo Maggio, il Giorno della Repubblica, il Giorno della Memoria, ...)?

Comment: @Charo This has nothing to do with festivities: see "ci vediamo il 2 maggio".

Comment: @Charo: Do you mean IV.20, rather than IV.18? In any case, yes. The use or lack of an article in front of names of days, months, seasons etc. is more more or less the same after _che programmi hai per_ as for most other sentences in which they are mentioned.

Comment: @DaG: Sorry, it was IV.17.d) instead of IV.18.

Comment: @Charo: Ah, yes, that's relevant!

Comment: @DaG:  As far as I have understood from this explanation by Serianni, definite articles are frequently used in some temporal expressions (such as the one of the question) with a role similar to that of a demonstrative adjective. However, it seems to me that there are some names that are usually written without article (months, days of week, some festivities), so one would write them without article even in such temporal expressions.

Comment: So, the idea would be that "che programmi hai per il pomeriggio?" would essentially mean "che programmi hai per questo pomeriggio?", "che programmi hai per l'estate?" would mean "che programmi hai per questa estate?", "che programmi hai per il fine settimana?" would mean "che programmi hai per questo fine settimana?", etc. However, the definite article is not used in this and other expressions with some names such as names of months, days of week and some festivities.

Comment: Do you think it would be  possible to try to write an answer, @DaG?

Comment: @Krzysztof Judging from your name you're Polish and this largely explains your doubts about the usage of articles, that your native language lacks completely. Well, it's not a simple question to answer: the Italian usage is quite peculiar also compared to other Romance languages.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to write an answer based on what I've found in the book *Italiano* by Luca Serianni. I hope someone else will improve it.

At section IV.17, referring to definite articles, Serianni explains:

> Talvolta la funzione dell'articolo [...] 
>    si avvicina a quella di un pronome o
>   aggettivo dimostrativo, rinnovando in
>   parte alcuni usi del dimostrativo latino *ĭlle*. Ecco i casi più notevoli:

That is,

> Sometimes the function of the article [...]
>    approaches that of a demonstrative pronoun or adjective, renewing in part of some uses of the Latin demonstrative *ĭlle*. Here are the most notable cases:

Among the cases mentioned, Serianni explains that definite articles whith a role quite similar to that of a demonstrative adjective are used with some temporal expressions (the meaning of the definite articles is explained in square brackets):

> d) Con alcune espressioni temporali: «entro la [questa] settimana»; «durante
>   l'[quella] estate vi furono molte novità»;
>   «Ma vedi già come dichina il [questo]
>   giorno» (Dante, *Purgatorio*, VII 43).

This is what happens with the temporal expression that appears in the question. Namely, "che programmi hai per il pomeriggio?" would essentially mean "che programmi hai per questo pomeriggio?", "che programmi hai per l'estate?" would mean "che programmi hai per questa estate?", "che programmi hai per il fine settimana?" would mean "che programmi hai per questo fine settimana?", etc.

However, at section IV.72, Serianni mentions that the article is not used in many cases. In the list of instances given, the only one which fits the expression given in the question is this one:

> i) Con i nomi dei mesi e dei giorni della
>   settimana [...]: «Aprile finì. Venne maggio» (Montefoschi, *Lo sguardo del cacciatore*, 91); «se volete... oggi è giovedì... domenica vi dico in chiesa» (Manzoni, *I Promessi Sposi*, XXX-VIII 21). Ma l'articolo può figurare quando il nome è accompagnato da una determinazione («Era il maggio odoroso» Leopardi, *A Silvia*, 13; «Era il giovedì grasso» Nievo) ed è obbligatorio quando
>   il costrutto ha valore distributivo (cfr. IV.20).

My translation:

> i) With the names of months and days of the week [...]:«Aprile finì. Venne maggio» (Montefoschi, *Lo sguardo del cacciatore*, 91); «se volete... oggi è giovedì... domenica vi dico in chiesa» (Manzoni, *I Promessi Sposi*, XXX-VIII 21). But the article may appear when the name is accompanied by a determination («Era il maggio odoroso» Leopardi, *A Silvia*, 13; «Era il giovedì grasso» Nievo) and it is mandatory when the construction has a distributive value (see IV.20).

That's why one says "che programmi hai per sabato?", "che programmi hai per gennaio?", etc.

It doesn't appear in the book, but it seems to me that something similar happens with the name of some festivities, that is, that some of them are usually written without article (Natale, Capodanno, Ferragosto, Pasqua, ...), whereas other ones are usually written with a definite article (il Primo Maggio, il Giorno della Repubblica, il Giorno della Memoria, ...). This would be the reason why one says, for instance, "che programmi hai per Capodanno?" or "che programmi hai per Natale?", written without the definite article.

In addition to all this, there are other cases in which the definitive article may be used in the expression which appears in the question for other reasons. This happens with a noun phrase used to express something that is felt as unique or specific and individual, such as in this example

> Che programmi hai per il giorno del ventesimo anniversario di tuo figlio?

and, as explained at section IV.60 of Serianni's book, with years, for instance

> Che programmi hai per il 2021?

So, the general idea would be that, with the time expression that appears in the question, the definite article is used except for some cases of names which are written without an article, such as the names of months, days of the week and some festivities.

Comment: I have made my answer community wiki in the hope some other users may improve it.

Comment: I don't think this is related to festivities. In "il primo maggio" the article is required by the date (as it would be in "il due maggio, which is not a festivity). In "il giorno" it's the word "giorno" that triggers the article, as in "il giorno del mio matrimonio", which is not a festivity either.

Answer (score -2):

If one takes into consideration your examples, the conclusion is that articles are required for periods of the day (morning etc.) and seasons, but not for months or days of the week. However, with regard to the latter two cases articles are required in contexts of specification: "il gennaio del 2010" (literally "the January of 2010") or "il sabato in cui tu non venisti" ("the Saturday in which you didn't come"). A short remark due to other observations in "Meta". The question pins down to the use of the article with regard to expressions of time. There is linguistically no "reason" why Italian generally uses articles with parts of the day, but not with months. The only phenomenon that can be explained is the one that I describe above and that relates to specification.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than a documented answer.